# How to delete multiple sections in table view in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I try to delete multiple sections I am getting this error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>
> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete section
> 5, but there are only 4 sections before the update'

Here is my code:

```
NSArray *selectedRows = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    
int i=0;

for (NSIndexPath *selectionIndex in selectedRows){
    
    
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [arrayToDelete objectAtIndex:i];
    [self.devices removeObject:[arrayToDelete objectAtIndex:i++]];
    [context deleteObject:managedObject];
    [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:selectionIndex.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}


[self saveContext];

[arrayToDelete removeAllObjects];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to inverse direction when you try to remove something in array.
that is:

```
//int i=0;

for (int i = [selectedRows count] - 1; i = 0; i-- ){

NSIndexPath *selectionIndex = selectedRows[i];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [arrayToDelete objectAtIndex:i];
    [self.devices removeObject:[arrayToDelete objectAtIndex:i]];
    [context deleteObject:managedObject];
    [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:selectionIndex.section] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```